# How to optimize external images on rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline

I have a successful rails app which is on the market.

The app fetches external images served by different Dealer management systems and showcases the images directly. However, running the speed tests shows that images itself are the culprits. They are taking 4+ MBs and is lowering the speed of the app. Especially for mobile phone browsers (40-50% of our customers use mobile phones), it has to be optimized.

My question is if I only want to showcase thumbnails, how can I use external images and showcase them on my website after optimizations ?

Using carrier wave and paperclip for our own uploaded image is fine and works great but is there any on the fly optimizations used in the industry for external images?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are displaying the images but make sure you're not storing really big images that are 4000x4000 and displaying it as 300x300. Also make sure your hosting provider isn't bottlenecking your loading, sometimes if your hosting provider is not that good or is in a bad location for where most of your traffic comes from this could cause loading issues.

Comment: `android studio` best practice is having different copies with different pixel density for the same image. After noticing this I started storing different pixel densities for my images and Just hiding those images on the mobile version and showing the lower pdi instead. Sass will be useful

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Yes I have done that with Android development or even the uploaded images on the website. But here I am talking about external images. We get data in CSV from all our clients every morning which has link to the image on their server. I showcase all thise on the website.